# jquery while loop fadeIn each <li> as it gets appended

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fiddle around with this concept and I can't seem to get the logic to work and stick.

I was wanting a user to enter a digit number and press the add link and when they do that it will add the number they entered as number of contacts and append each new contact to an `<li>` element, then fade them in one at a time. If the user where to enter another number in the text field for it to then append that new number to the end of the li with an incremented number.

For instance:

```
[_3_] [Add]
============
Contact 1
Contact 2
Contact 3
```

Then if they decide to add 2 more contacts:

```
[_2_] [Add]
============
Contact 1
Contact 2
Contact 3
Contact 4
Contact 5
```

this is my code: the ID of the UL is new-prospect-add-contacts

```
//-- Add more contacts

var counter = $("#new-prospect-add-contacts").size();

    $("#e").live("click", function(){


        var e = $("#new-prospect-additional-contact").val();
        while(counter < e)
        {
            $("#new-prospect-add-contacts").append("<li>").append("<span>Contact " + ++counter + "</span>").fadeIn(2000);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Behaviors:

I am able to add the number of Contacts based on user input, but they will flash into the `<UL>` and not apply the `.fadeIn()`

If a user adds more contacts It appends it to the bottom but starts the count all over again from 2....

Comment: FYI, `id`'s should be unique. `var counter = $("#new-prospect-add-contacts").size();` might not give you the expected value in every browser.

Comment: They Reigel, long time now see :) ya thats the ID of the UL

Comment: hehe. Technically we still haven't met even once. Back to my comment, `var counter = $("#new-prospect-add-contacts").size();` should be `var counter = $("#new-prospect-add-contacts > li").size();` to count the number of `li` which I think what you really wanted. :)

Comment: oh hmmm, add ur comment as an asnwer so i can mark it! oh, dunno if its me but as a side affect after the first click nothing happens. I can't add anymore contacts... hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**See working demo of the following code here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9pagu/)

Instead of using a counter, I used `$("#new-prospect-add-contacts").find('li').length` being dynamically updated as the list grows to count how many to add, based on how many were already in the list when we start plus the amount to add.

```
var $npac = $("#new-prospect-add-contacts"),
    addVal = parseInt($("#new-prospect-additional-contact").val(), 10) + $npac.find('li').length;

while ($npac.find('li').length < addVal) {
    // CODE
}
```

Since we don't cache the length, the while loop will break when we append enough `li` to the list.  Inside the `while` we append the `li` items as hidden...

```
    var nLi = $('<li><span>Contact ' +
                parseInt($npac.find('li').length + 1, 10) + 
                '</span></li>').css('display', 'none');
    $npac.append(nLi);
```

...so that afterwards we can iterate through them with `.each()` and use the index to delay when they `fadeIn()`:

```
$npac.find('li:hidden').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).delay((i+1)*150).fadeIn(600);
});
```

[See demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/9pagu/)

Answer (score 2):

your callback scope is destroyed after each 'click', so your `counter` will not persist.

you could move the counter declaration outside the callback in your script, and it will persist.